# How to summarize, group 4000+ GPX Trackpoints as Tracks named for by each days date?

Tags: xml, xslt, gps, gpx

the XSLT below extracts all Trackpoints (trkpt) only from a Garmin GPX-file (omiting any Waypoints) and exports the result as one (1) track into a new GPX-file ready for MapSource or Basecamp.
Currently the name of that one track is the date of the first Trackpoint.

How can I achieve to have one track per day named for by each date (YYYY-MM-DD), where each track includes all its corresponding trackpoints?

(I believe that the date change in trkpt/time must be taken into account, but I am lost here).

The GPX-sourcefile can be any larger GPX-file created by Garmin (don't know about others).
My source-file spans over 3 months of travel with trackpoint records taken every four minutes (total of 7633 trkpt during 75 days).
Of course, the device was turned of while sleeping.
Below please see the XSLT-code of the file named as: 'extract-TRKPTs.xsl'

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:gpx="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
<!-- command: msxsl.exe 20101008.gpx extract-TRKPTs.xsl > 20101008-trkpts.gpx -->
<!-- extracts all trackpoints only from a given Garmin GPX file -->
<!-- output is piped into a new .gpx file -->
<xsl:template match="/">&#60;<xsl:text>?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?&#62;</xsl:text>
&#60;<xsl:text>gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" creator="MapSource 6.16.2" version="1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"</xsl:text>&#62;
<gpx>
<trk>&#60;trk&#62;
&#60;name&#62;Trackpoints: <xsl:value-of select="substring(/gpx:gpx/gpx:trk/gpx:trkseg/gpx:trkpt/gpx:time,1,10)"/>&#60;/name&#62;
<trkseg>&#60;trkseg&#62;
    <xsl:for-each select="/gpx:gpx/gpx:trk/gpx:trkseg/gpx:trkpt">
    <xsl:value-of select="gpx:trkpt"/><trkpt>
        &#60;<xsl:text>trkpt lat="</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@lat"/><xsl:text>" lon="</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@lon"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>&#62;
        &#60;ele&#62;<xsl:value-of select="gpx:ele"/>&#60;/ele&#62;
        &#60;time&#62;<xsl:value-of select="gpx:time"/>&#60;/time&#62;
        &#60;/trkpt&#62;</trkpt>
    </xsl:for-each>
</trkseg>&#60;/trkseg&#62;
</trk>&#60;/trk&#62;
</gpx>&#60;/gpx&#62;
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The code looks ugly because it's set to output 'text' hence I needed to use special-character-entities. But hey, so far it works. Sorry, I am an XSLT-novice.
Thanks for feedback.

Current output is as follows (all trackpoints in one single track):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" creator="MapSource 6.16.2" version="1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
<trk>
<name>Trackpoints: 2010-09-21</name>
<trkseg>
    <trkpt lat="34.004124635830522" lon="-118.47464606165886">
    <ele>55.4130859375</ele>
    <time>2010-09-21T19:51:12Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="34.004120444878936" lon="-118.47464254125953">
    <ele>55.4130859375</ele>
    <time>2010-09-21T19:51:26Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="34.004129162058234" lon="-118.47465343773365">
    <ele>56.8551025390625</ele>
    <time>2010-09-22T21:02:55Z</time>
    </trkpt>
...
...
    <trkpt lat="37.042149296030402" lon="-112.52694656141102">
    <ele>1506.523193359375</ele>
    <time>2010-12-01T07:01:06Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="37.042256919667125" lon="-112.52645093947649">
    <ele>1504.1201171875</ele>
    <time>2010-12-01T07:01:23Z</time>
    </trkpt>
</trkseg>
</trk>
</gpx>
```

The expected output is as follows (please note: one track per day).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" creator="MapSource 6.16.2" version="1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
<trk>
<name>Trackpoints: 2010-09-21</name>
<trkseg>
    <trkpt lat="34.004124635830522" lon="-118.47464606165886">
    <ele>55.4130859375</ele>
    <time>2010-09-21T19:51:12Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="34.004120444878936" lon="-118.47464254125953">
    <ele>55.4130859375</ele>
    <time>2010-09-21T19:51:26Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="34.004129162058234" lon="-118.47465343773365">
    <ele>56.8551025390625</ele>
    <time>2010-09-22T21:02:55Z</time>
    </trkpt>
</trkseg>
</trk>
...
...
<trk>
<name>Trackpoints: 2010-12-01</name>
<trkseg>

    <trkpt lat="37.042149296030402" lon="-112.52694656141102">
    <ele>1506.523193359375</ele>
    <time>2010-12-01T07:01:06Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="37.042256919667125" lon="-112.52645093947649">
    <ele>1504.1201171875</ele>
    <time>2010-12-01T07:01:23Z</time>
    </trkpt>
</trkseg>
</trk>
</gpx>
```

Comment: Why is the output method set to "text" if you actually output XML? Also, please edit your post to show the _expected_ output and how exactly it differs from the one you currently get.

Comment: @Mathias Müller: added expected output. Reason for text-output is the formatting of the node '<trkpt lat=....'. Would certainly prefer a clean and not so ugly code. However it works so far.

Comment: Thanks for editing. What do you mean by the reason is "the formatting of the node"? I am still not with you. As a last request, please post a sample GPX file we can use as XML input (I guess very few people here are familiar with GPX).

Comment: @Mathias Müller: sample gpx-file is placed on my server: [www.halo-photographs.com/exchange/2010-09-21_2010-12-06.gpx]. Referring to your question: I was not able to add the attributes 'lat' and 'lon' to the node 'trkpt' using xml as output. That is the reason I declared the code posted above as 'ugly' - and yes it is an ugly hack. Nothing more, but what the heck - it does work. As you know XML- and GPX-file structures and their transformations follow the same rules. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: +1 Finally, your question is helpful and worth an upvote!

Comment: @Mathias Müller - Thank you too! Do you have a suggestion how to output to xml? I couldn't find a solution for the attributes 'lat', 'lon' in 'trkpt'. Maybe I should post another question for that.

Comment: You should _definitely_ set the output method to "xml". Setting attributes is not so hard - and yes, I recommend you open a new question. But make sure the following information is there from the beginning: Input XML, the actual output vs. the one you expect, an explanation of what exactly should happen - and your XSLT code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Since you didn't supply example input, I made my own (modified version of the example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format#Sample_GPX_document)).

**XML Input**

```
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" 
    xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3"
    xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1" 
    creator="Oregon 400t" 
    version="1.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv1.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <link href="http://www.garmin.com">
            <text>Garmin International</text>
        </link>
        <time>2009-10-17T22:58:43Z</time>
    </metadata>
    <trk>
        <name>Example 1</name>
        <trkseg>
            <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326897">
                <ele>4.46</ele>
                <time>2009-10-17T18:37:26Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326898">
                <ele>4.47</ele>
                <time>2009-10-17T18:38:26Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326898">
                <ele>4.48</ele>
                <time>2009-10-18T18:39:26Z</time>
            </trkpt>
        </trkseg>
    </trk>
    <trk>
        <name>Example 2</name>
        <trkseg>
            <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326899">
                <ele>4.49</ele>
                <time>2009-10-18T18:37:26Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326900">
                <ele>4.50</ele>
                <time>2009-10-18T18:38:26Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326901">
                <ele>4.51</ele>
                <time>2009-10-19T18:39:26Z</time>
            </trkpt>
        </trkseg>    
    </trk>
</gpx>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" 
    xmlns:gpx="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="gpx">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="date" match="gpx:trkpt" use="substring(gpx:time,1,10)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="//gpx:trkpt[generate-id(key('date',substring(gpx:time,1,10))[1])=generate-id()]">
                <trk>
                    <name>Trackpoints: <xsl:value-of select="substring(gpx:time,1,10)"/></name>
                    <trkseg>
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('date',substring(gpx:time,1,10))">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </trkseg>
                </trk>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
     xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3"
     xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     creator="Oregon 400t"
     version="1.1"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv1.xsd">
   <trk>
      <name>Trackpoints: 2009-10-17</name>
      <trkseg>
         <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326897">
            <ele>4.46</ele>
            <time>2009-10-17T18:37:26Z</time>
         </trkpt>
         <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326898">
            <ele>4.47</ele>
            <time>2009-10-17T18:38:26Z</time>
         </trkpt>
      </trkseg>
   </trk>
   <trk>
      <name>Trackpoints: 2009-10-18</name>
      <trkseg>
         <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326898">
            <ele>4.48</ele>
            <time>2009-10-18T18:39:26Z</time>
         </trkpt>
         <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326899">
            <ele>4.49</ele>
            <time>2009-10-18T18:37:26Z</time>
         </trkpt>
         <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326900">
            <ele>4.50</ele>
            <time>2009-10-18T18:38:26Z</time>
         </trkpt>
      </trkseg>
   </trk>
   <trk>
      <name>Trackpoints: 2009-10-19</name>
      <trkseg>
         <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326901">
            <ele>4.51</ele>
            <time>2009-10-19T18:39:26Z</time>
         </trkpt>
      </trkseg>
   </trk>
</gpx>
```

Comment: thanks fro feedback. I'm getting an error: Code:   0x80004005
Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

/gpx:trkpt[-->generate-id(key('date',substring(gpx:time,1,10)))<--[1]=generate-id()]

Comment: sample gpx-file is placed on my server: [www.halo-photographs.com/exchange/2010-09-21_2010-12-06.gpx]

Comment: @snahl - Sorry. Had a typo that doesn't cause an error with the XSLT 2.0 processor I was using. I updated my answer.

Comment: @snahl - Did you use the updated stylesheet? Be sure the first `xsl:for-each` has the select `//gpx:trkpt[generate-id(key('date',substring(gpx:time,1,10))[1])=generate-id()]`. It works for me using both data sets and either Xalan or Saxon 6.5.5 as the 1.0 processor.

Comment: Just saw it after posting. This time around it works great! Just pumped my 1.4MB sample file through and after 2 mins it opened flawlessly in MapSource - BINGO! Many thanks. Can I ask you another question related to this case?

Comment: @snahl - Sure! If it would help the community, go ahead and create a new stackoverflow question. Otherwise feel free to create a chat room or send me an email (my email is in my profile).

Comment: Question is posted at: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514857/alternating-colors-in-gpx-tracks]