# Alternating colors in GPX-Tracks

Tags: xml, gps, xslt-1.0, gpx

This Question refers to:[How to summarize, group 4000+ GPX Trackpoints as Tracks named for by each days date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510509/how-to-summarize-group-4000-gpx-trackpoints-as-tracks-named-for-by-each-days-d)

Garmin GPS-Tracks provide the option to define a different color for each track.

As a perfection to the result of the referring question, I wonder how to apply alternating colors for each GPS-track. For instance the 1st. track (all trackpoints for that day) are colored 'Magenta' the 2nd. day is colored 'DarkGray' and the 3rd. day again 'Magenta'.

Using the node  (date) to alternate between odd or even days would often produce the same color for 2 days. For example: March 31 to April 1st. would receive the same colors.

Colors apply to the node: <gpxx:DisplayColor>

How can this be achieved using the code provided in the answer of the referring question?

```
<trk>
<name>ACTIVE LOG</name>
<extensions>
  <gpxx:TrackExtension xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3">
    <gpxx:DisplayColor>Magenta</gpxx:DisplayColor>
  </gpxx:TrackExtension>
</extensions>
<trkseg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can divide the `position()` by 2 and check to see if there is a remainder.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" 
    xmlns:gpx="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" 
    xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="gpx">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="date" match="gpx:trkpt" use="substring(gpx:time,1,10)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="//gpx:trkpt[generate-id(key('date',substring(gpx:time,1,10))[1])=generate-id()]">
                <trk>
                    <name>Trackpoints: <xsl:value-of select="substring(gpx:time,1,10)"/></name>
                    <extensions>
                        <gpxx:TrackExtension>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">
                                    <gpxx:DisplayColor>Magenta</gpxx:DisplayColor>                                    
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <gpxx:DisplayColor>DarkGray</gpxx:DisplayColor>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </gpxx:TrackExtension>
                    </extensions>
                    <trkseg>
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('date',substring(gpx:time,1,10))">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </trkseg>
                </trk>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perfect, many thanks!! Please note: Garmin is a British company so edit 'DarkGrey' to 'DarkGray' and all is fine.

Comment: +1 The fact that you made this edit alone is worth the upvote.

Comment: @Mathias Müller - thanks Mathias. By the way, this XSLT also works with Garmin-GPX files containing waypoints (that will get stripped off). The output result turns out to be the cleanest collection (that I have seen) of all trackpoints sorted per day. No more messy ACTIVE LOG entries in MapSource and BaseCamp.

Comment: @snahl Er, I did not mean you, actually. I meant Daniel of course, for being so endlessly nice and even edit in your (in a way) nit-picking remark about British spelling that has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @Mathias Müller - Sorry, I did not mean to be nit-picking at all. The reason I pointed this out is simply that the resulting output of this great XSLT provided by Daniel would not load in MapSource nor BaseCamp when writing DarkGrey instead of (british) DarkGray. Also I did not realize until now that I can attempt an edit on other persons answer. However, all is well now.

Comment: @snahl That's okay, now your remark makes more sense to me. Apologies for the harsh comment!

Comment: This works like a charm - the results are very useful! A slight drawback is when using a large source file with 60000 plus records (in this case trackpoints) it takes a very long time to process (over an hour on a decent machine). Is there a chance to speed-up the processing? Like would it be meaningful to create intermediary output files like extracting all trkpts, then group and sort them by date and then sort within the groups by time? In a smaller test-set with 5000 trkpts processing time is fine.